# How to run map inside map function in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want my axios part should run first inside useEffect so that my state can be update first and then further I can use that.

Here is error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property map of undefined
```

When I console it shows states is not updated it holds `SwitchCOM` empty array

That means it directly goes for the `return` statement without running `useEffect` axios part.

This is what my `SwitchCom` state look like:

```
SwitchCOM: {
  0: {id: "36", name: "XYZ", progress: "", details: [{id: "36", name: "XYZ", progress: ""}]},
  1: {id: "83", name: "ABC", progress: "",  details: [{id: "36", name: "XYZ", progress: ""}]},
  2: {id: "77", name: "EFG", progress: "",  details: [{id: "36", name: "XYZ", progress: "" }]}
}
```

```
const initialState = {
    SwitchCOM: [],
    isFetching: false,
    hasError: false
}
```

```
{states.SwitchCOM.map(topis => (
  <div className="item" key={topis.id}>
    <p>{topis.name}</p>
    <p>
      <progress id="file" value="32" max="100">
        {topis.progress}
      </progress>
    </p>
    {topis.activities.map(activity => (
      <table key={activity.id}>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Progress</td>
            <td>Status</td>
          </tr>
          <tr >
            <td>{activity.name}</td>
            <td>{activity.prog}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    ))}
  </div>
))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to map through an object which won't work. Instead you need to use `Object.keys(...)` to accomplish what you want here.

You should do something like this:

```
{Object.keys(states.SwitchCOM).map(key => (
  <div className="item" key={states.SwitchCOM[key].id}>
    <p>{states.SwitchCOM[key].name}</p>
    <p>
      <progress id="file" value="32" max="100">
        {states.SwitchCOM[key].progress}
      </progress>
    </p>
    {states.SwitchCOM[key].details.map(detail => (
      <table key={detail.id}>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Progress</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>{detail.name}</td>
            <td>{detail.progress}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    ))}
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: hi @Barry Michael Doyle i made the changes in my code but again my map is not running as i have called map inside of map ```SwitchCOM: []``` contain an array activities which also i want to run

Comment: hi @Barry Michael Doyle I just update my question how my state look like

Comment: Hi @Barry Michael Doyle  if i write in this way ```topis.details.map(detail => ``` it throws error topis is not defined

Comment: its look something like this Inside of SwitchCOM  array  ```{ 0: {id: "36", name: "XYZ", progress: "", details: [{id: "36", name: "XYZ", progress: ""}]}```

Comment: I think its and array of object ```{SwitchCOM : Array(5), isFetching: true, hasError: false}``` and inside of SwitchCOM when i open  ```{ 0: {id: "36", name: "XYZ", progress: "", details: [{id: "36", name: "XYZ", progress: ""}]}```

Comment: Thanx a lot its working Could you comment out the things